# How to write array for each operation result as a new array

Tags: c#, arrays

Trying to process Array float data and keep it as new array for later use. Got a float[] of 10 items and want to do math with each item and save result on new array. Getting "cant convert float to float" error. Thanks for the help, could not find what im searching for on Google sorry if it's dup.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proyecto X0n-832, Codificación de la teoría musical.");
    //Variables Generales
    float[] eau = { 440, 20000 };
    float fnd = eau[0];
    float cyc = fnd * 2;
    //Se cambia sfn por sbf    
    float[] sbf = { fnd, cyc, cyc * 2, cyc * 4, cyc * 8, cyc * 16, cyc * 32, cyc * 64, cyc * 128, cyc * 256 };

    //Imprimir la información hasta ahora:
    Console.WriteLine("Rango audible definido entre " + eau[0] + " y " + eau[1] + " Hz");
    Console.WriteLine("Frecuencia fundamental: " + fnd);
    Console.WriteLine("Lista de ciclos (octavas): ");
    // Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", sbf));
    foreach (float i in sbf)
    {
        float[] icant = Math.Sqrt(i);
        Console.WriteLine(i*2);
    }
}
```

// Edit: added Linq and code shared in comments but it still has errors:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Proyecto X0n-832, Codificación de la teoría musical.");
        //Variables Generales
        float[] eau = { 440, 20000 };
        float fnd = eau[0];
        float cyc = fnd * 2;
        //Se cambia sfn por sbf    
        float[] sbf = { fnd, cyc, cyc * 2, cyc * 4, cyc * 8, cyc * 16, cyc * 32, cyc * 64, cyc * 128, cyc * 256 };

        //Imprimir la información hasta ahora:
        Console.WriteLine("Rango audible definido entre " + eau[0] + " y " + eau[1] + " Hz");
        Console.WriteLine("Frecuencia fundamental: " + fnd);
        Console.WriteLine("Lista de ciclos (octavas): ");
        // Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", sbf));
        var icant = sbf.Select(i => Math.Sqrt(i)).ToArray() // icant is an arry here
        sbf.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i * 2));
    }
```

Comment: `float[] icant = Math.Sqrt(i);` why should that return an array?

Comment: idk im realy noob, how would u perform that operation? save results of recursive operation to new referenciable array pls help

Comment: `float[] icant = sbf.Select(item => (float)Math.Sqrt(item)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `foreach` block. Type of output of `Math.Sqrt(i)` is not `float[]` it is `float`.
What I assume you want is:

```
var icant = sbf.Select(i => Math.Sqrt(i)).ToArray(); // icant is an arry here
Array.ForEach(sbf, i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

I just used `linq` extension methods to do the job. If you don't feel comfortable with that :

```
var result = new float[sbf.Length];
for( var i = 0; i < sbf.Length; i++) 
{
    result[i] = Math.Sqrt(sbf[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(i*2);
}
```

Comment: Better, but now i got this error: CS7036 and CS1061 “…Does Not Contain Definition and No Extension Method…accepting a first argument of type ” could be found and

Comment: one agian sorry if this sounds very dumb im really new at this

Comment: @Xiutek I updated my answer. `Array` has no non-static method named `ForEach`, in despite of `List<T>`.  It is defined as an static method, and I was wrong in using it like a nonstatic one. Now it's correct.

Comment: Thank you, you are very kind. I added using System.Linq; and got rid of previous errors but poped two new ones: CS1002 "Expected ;" (on line 32) and CS7036 No method for action, ill edit code

Comment: @Xiutek Any statement should end with a semicolon. Make sure all statements around line 32 do end with a `;`

Comment: @Xiutek your welcome. This is what stackoverflow is for!